# Keeping registry window open while executing R script in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r

I'm trying to execute an R script in QGIS that already worked in another PC. However now it's not working and the window is automatically closed when the processes of the script finishes.

Is there any piece of code to paste at the end of an R script to keep this window in order to see what is been executed?

This is the screen shot that I get if I'm quick enough to catch it. How could I keep this window opened?

[image]

Comment: Go to `Processing > Options` ,and in General list activate `Keep dialog open after running an algorithm` ,I'm using QGIS 2.18.15

Comment: @FranciscoRaga please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only need go to `Processing > Options` ,and in *General* list activate `Keep dialog open after running an algorithm` ,

Tested using **QGIS 2.18.15**